# How to scale SolrField value from 0 to 1

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr5, solr-boost

I am working on Solr5+

I want to scale a Price field from 0 to 1 to apply boosting.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[Function queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries) allow you to create complex formula to be used for ranking. You probably would use something like **map** function.